# setting the id using dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building my drowdown lists like this:

> var ratingInfo = 
>      (from rl in Model.RatingSet.Where(x=>x.QuestionID ==  @item.QuestionID 
>      && x.ShowForPerson == true).OrderBy(x=>x.OptionPosition) 
>      select new { Value = rl.OptionKey, Text = rl.Option});
>
> var Rating = new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)
>      ratingInfo, "Value", "Text", @item.Rating);

```
<td class="center">@Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.RatingSet[iCount].OptionKey, Rating)</td>
```

Everything is displaying perfectly.  However, when I try to submit the form and any changes I make to the rating dropdown I am unable to see the new value.

I think it has something do to with the ID of the dropdown not being equal to the model value I have set.

If that is the case, how do I set the DropDown list id value (using the `DropDownListFor` method)?

**This is the output of the HTML code for the drop down list:**

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OptionKey must be a number." data-val-required="The OptionKey field is required." 
id="RatingSet_0__OptionKey" name="RatingSet[0].OptionKey">
<option value="5">---</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
<option value="4">D</option>
</select>
```

**Answer:**

Based on 48klocs comment I started to notice something that was wrong in my code.
I wasn't using the correct item from my model to build my dropdownlist.  Once I did that:

```
<td class="center">@Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.ResultSet[iCount].Rating, Rating)</td>
```

Everything started to work like it should.

Comment: Is it possible to show the code that is rendered on the page please? Perhaps there is a clue there.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake I updated my question to show the output of the HTML code

Comment: Only the `name` element matters for postback; the `id` is only used for client-side code.

Comment: @48klocs - How do I change my name in the <select> tag?

Comment: You generally don't (I think you can override it with an overload that accepts an anonymous type), you make sure that your model and controller actions are all in line (a collection of `RatingSet`s is certainly being posted back; are you sure that your result is being told to listen for and autobind to them?).

Comment: @48klocs - I actually figured it out.  It was something dumb on my part.